# How to split a dataframe with missing values?

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe that I need to split based on the values in one of the columns - most of them are either 0 or 1, but a couple are NA, which I can't get to form a subset. This is what I've done:

```
all <- read.csv("XXX.csv")
splitted <- split(all, all$case_con)

dim(splitted[[1]]) #--> gives me 185
dim(splitted[[2]]) #--> gives me 180
```

but all contained 403 rows, which means that 38 NA values were left out and I don't know how to form a similar subset to the ones above with them. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is better to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). That makes it a lot easier for other people to help you.

Comment: Hacky soln would just be to replace the NAs with a dummy value before splitting

Comment: Can you run `sapply(splitted, dim)`? This will tell us if you have any NAs in your `case_con` variable.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik

`sapply(splitted,dim)
            0       1
[1,]   185   180
[2,] 2273 2273`

but 

`dim(all) #--> [1] 403 2273`

So I'm losing the remaining values that are neither in splitted[[1]] nor in splitted[[2]]

Comment: @julia please edit this information into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
splitted<-c(split(all, all$case_con,list(subset(all, is.na(case_con))))
```

This should tack on the data frame subset with the NAs as the last one in the list...

Answer (score 0):

```
list(split(all, all$cases_con), split(all, is.na(all$cases_con)))
```

I think it would be work. Ty